# Maven plugin in not getting executed

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a custom maven plugin but when i use that in my project pom , it does not get triggered !
Here is how i using same:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.autodeploy.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-docs-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2-0</version>
                  <inherited>false</inherited>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>myid</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>install</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/doc</outputDirectory>
                    <custom-Folders>
                        <param>${basedir}/files/</param>
                    </custom-Folders>
                </configuration>
                </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I am triggering build cycle like mvn install:install or even mvn install ! None of these invoke my maven plugin !

Comment: 1. Did you define your plugin in `<plugins>` or in `<pluginManagement>`? 2. Is the goal in your plugin really called `install`? Note furthermore, that `mvn install:install` will not call your plugin, but `mvn install` should usually call it.

Comment: I have defined plugin in under <pluginManagement> .                          Like <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>     Goal i defined from my self!

Comment: Even i tried moving it out of <pluginManagement> . It is not working !

Comment: So first thing is to move the plugin to the `<plugins>` section outside `<pluginManagement>`. Then run `mvn install`. Your plugin should be called.

Comment: I am getting this error :Plugin com.autodeploy.maven:my-docs-plugin:1.0.2-0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.autodeploy.maven:my-docs-plugin:jar:1.0.2-10 ! THough i have this plugin published in nexus !

Comment: I would check in Nexus if this is exactly the version you build and if it was deployed to the correct repository in Maven.

Comment: Ok my repository is fine and version also ! Do you we need to put dependency also on this plugin just like we express other artefact dependencies!

Comment: No. If the plugin is in the right repository with the right coordinates, Maven will find it.